# what is the best way to export 3D plots in Latex

Tags: matlab2tikz

I'm using bar3 plots from Matlab but the problem is the plots in Latex are not the same as in Matlab [image: Matlab plot][image: PDF Latex]

Comment: It looks like the surfaces in the tikz plot are being drawn in the wrong order--starting with the surfaces closest to the viewpoint, so that the farther surfaces are drawn on top of them.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the pgf-documentation  and figure out what excately doesnt't work (http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf eg. p. 66) . If you like, post the matlab to tikz output file.